# Getting FATAL EXCEPTION of MultipartEntityBuilder

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am getting Fatal Exception while creating FileBody using URI file path of **NoClassDefFoundError** here is my code.

```
 try {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpContext httpContext = new BasicHttpContext();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(URLIMG);
        try{

            MultipartEntityBuilder multipartEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
            multipartEntity.addPart("userfile", new FileBody(new File(file.getPath())));
            // Send it
            httpPost.setEntity(multipartEntity.build());
            Log.e("post" , httpPost.toString());
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, httpContext);
            String serverResponse = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            Log.e("sd","serverResponse = "+serverResponse);
        }catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("Exception", "Exception: " + e.toString());
        }
    }catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("Exception", "Exception: " + e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

and my Log is:

```
01-04 18:15:13.881 15372-15372/com.example.hp_pc.cerv E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                    Process: com.example.hp_pc.cerv, PID: 15372
                                                                    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/http/entity/ContentType;
                                                                        at org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody.<init>(FileBody.java:89)
```

Comment: show your build.gradle

Comment: I have this
packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    }
and 
compile files('libs/httpclient-4.2.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpcore.jar')

Comment: try to have all libs with one version, it could be a problem

Comment: i applied that but nothing work

Answer (score 0):

As [ContentType.java](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/ContentType.html) is available in httpcore since v4.2. you most likely use a wrong version of httpcore.

To fix this, search an artifact repository for the correct version of httpcore, which in your case is [4.2.2](https://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcomponents-client/4.2.3/httpcomponents-client-4.2.3.pom), [download it](https://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.apache.httpcomponents%7Chttpcomponents-core%7C4.2.2%7Cpom) and exchange it with your current version.

Without knowing about your build system, it could also be the case, that you are not shipping the httpcore.jar. In this case, make sure to use the same mechanics as with the other two jars.

To prevent these kind of issue use the dependency management feature of modern build systems, in your case most likely [Gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html) or at least keep the version numbers on jar files.